# How to specify multiple images as source to signalstats filter with FFProbe?

Tags: ffprobe

The [signalstats](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#signalstats-1) of a single image can be calculated via ffprobe with this command:

```
ffprobe -f lavfi -i "movie=0000002110.jpg,signalstats,metadata=print"
```

I'd like to do this in a folder with sequential file numbers. In ffmpeg I'm able to achieve this sort of input like this:

```
ffmpeg -start_number 1036 -i %010d.jpg -vf "crop=100:100:0:0" \cropped\%010d.jpg
```

The [filter documentation for the movie parameter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#movie-1) implies that if I might have the right format or stream specifier things might go better.

I am able to get ffmpeg to do it with a standard -i via:

```
ffmpeg -start_number 2110 -i %010d.jpg -vf signalstats,metadata=print -f null -
```

FFProbe would be better for my target environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the syntax for reading an image sequence with ffprobe.

```
ffprobe -f lavfi -i "movie='%010d.jpg':f=image2:format_opts='start_number=2110',signalstats,metadata=print" -v 0 -show_entries frame_tags
```

The data will be printed to stdout.

Comment: This isn't working for me, it seems to have trouble extracting 'format_opts'. Removing the -v 0 here's what I get:

ffprobe -f lavfi -i "movie='%010d.jpg':f=image2:format_opts='start_number=2110',signalstats,metadata=print" -show_entries frame_tags


[Parsed_movie_0 @ 000001e4d923f000] Option 'format_opts' not found
[lavfi @ 000001e4d923d300] Error initializing filter 'movie' with args '%010d.jpg:f=image2:format_opts=start_number=2110'
movie='%010d.jpg':f=image2:format_opts='start_number=2110',signalstats,metadata=print: Option not found

Comment: ffprobe version 4.0.2

Comment: You'll need 5.0 or newer.